# If the file I am trying to read is in the same package as the java file I'm working with, why am I still getting a "FileNotFoundException"?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to read a file in my java program called `HelloJavaTest.java`
but I keep on getting a `FileNotFoundException` error.

The file I'm trying to import (`hello.txt`) is in the same package as `HelloJavaTest.java` (package: java_files).

Here is the message that pops up when I try to compile the code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \java_files\hello.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
at java_files.HelloJavaTest.main(HelloJavaTest.java:42)
```

Here is what I have at the top of my code:

```
import java.io.*;  // for File
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: Looks like a relative link...

Comment: Reading and importing are unrelated. Most likely you are using a wrong path. Add the code where you open the file.

Comment: Try `"java_files/hello.txt"`

Comment: If you want to load things from the classpath, use Class.getInputStream. Relative paths for FileInputStream have nothing to do with where the source files are (which on a normal end-user machine do not even exist), but depends on the current working directory.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments have correctly pointed that file reading and importing packages are not related.

Here `\java_files\hello.txt` looks like the program is trying to find `java_files` directory in the root directory `\`, but is not able to find it.

You should not fiddle with paths if the file is located within the project.

Try using

```
URL url = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.txt");
System.out.println(url.getPath());
File f = new File(url.getPath());
```

Use the **class loader** to find the resource.